# How do I prevent padding from throwing off my DIV widths?

Tags: html, css, width, padding

I have two DIVs, which I would like to stack vertically …

```
<div id="searchContainer”>…</div>
<div id="searchResultsContainer”>…</div>
```

I have the following styles assigned to them …

```
#searchContainer {
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: "Calibre", "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", "Roboto", "Arial", sans-serif;
  background-color: tan;
  width: 100%;
}

#searchResultsContainer {
  background-color:cyan;
  font-family: "Calibre", "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", "Roboto", "Arial", sans-serif;
  padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

However it seems that adding padding to my top DIV causes it to be wider than the DIV below it.  I would like both DIVs to be the same width, but I would like the top DIV to have the padding so that the elements don’t scrunch up to the border.  How do I do that?  Here is the Fiddle that illustrates my problem — https://jsfiddle.net/1zb5mqmo/ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `box-sizing: border-box;` on the padded div:

```
#searchContainer {
    padding: 10px;
    font-family: "Calibre", "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", "Roboto", "Arial", sans-serif;
    background-color: tan;
    /* max-width: 1000px; */
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

`box-sizing: border-box` The width and height properties include the content padding and border

`box-sizing: content-box` The width and height properties include only content

Updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1zb5mqmo/1/)

Answer (score 0):

In this case, simply remove the width and you can combine both padding and border without throwing it off

```css
#searchContainer {
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: "Calibre", "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", "Roboto", "Arial", sans-serif;
  background-color: tan;
}

#searchResultsContainer {
  background-color:cyan;
  font-family: "Calibre", "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", "Roboto", "Arial", sans-serif;
  padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
  border: 5px solid steelblue
}
```

```html
<div id="searchContainer">...</div>
<div id="searchResultsContainer">...</div>
```